# how to implement regex for intron search dna sequence.. - Bioinformatic

Tags: python

i was doing a code in python 3 to find introns as a subsequence from a dna_sequence. So i search a lot of theory about introns and some libraries and functions as "re" and i only got the first intron in the sequence but i want to get the positition where the intron starts ant put it on a list.
P.D. the output is only the first intron found, but if we add some blank spaces, the code keeps going and find the indexes of the another ones. 
P.D2 i know that Regex doesn't work in superposition text

CODE BELOW

```
import re
def buscar_intrones(adn_sec):
    lista = []
    consulta = re.compile("(GT)([ACTG]{1,10})(TACTAAC)([ACTG]{1,10}AC)")
    iterador = re.finditer(consulta, adn_sec)

    for intron in iterador:
        #print(intron.start(), intron.group())
        lista.append([intron.start(), intron.group()])

    return lista

sec = "GTTACTAACTACTAACGTAACTACTAACCAC"
print(buscar_intrones(sec))
```

Output: [[0, 'GTTACTAACTACTAACGTAACTACTAAC']]
Expected: [[0, 'GTTACTAACTAC'], [16, 'GTAACTACTAACCAC']]

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job. They are going to be so slow, especially in the Python implementation, as to be unusable for this type of problem other than against trivial inputs. The main problem with your approach is that python regex matches are "greedy" by default. That is, an expression like `[ACTG]{1,10}` will match the longest sequence that allows the remaining expressions to also match the input. Which is true for your regex and input. Using the `?` modifier to request a non-greedy match often helps in this type of situation but will not fix your example. That's because `TACTAAC` occurs multiple times in the input and the surrounding bytes match the shortest to longest variable length expressions.

You might be able to construct a regex that works as you desire but it is going to be complicated (hard to understand), slow, and likely to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an algorithm like the Boyer-Moore string search algorithm. There is a Python implementation of the Boyer-Moore algorithm in the pympler package.
For example:

```
from pympler.boyer_moore import BoyerMoore

dna_sequence = 'GTTACTAACTACTAACGTAACTACTAACCAC'
intron_sequence = 'TACTAAC'

bm = BoyerMoore(intron_sequence)

# Find all occurrences of the intron sequence in the dna_sequence
matches = bm.find_all(dna_sequence)

print(matches)
```